# Application Pool Suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Tags: web, crash, application-pool

So the company I work for has been having this issue for years. We continuously get this error almost every other day. After the application pool crashes, it does reboot. However, we're having customers submit their applications/deals to our website and instead are encountering errors due to this app pool crashing/rebooting. I've searched extensively online and on YouTube trying to fix this issue. However, I have had no luck in finding a fix.

Has anyone had to deal with this issue before, and do you happen to have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 'System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll' use the dll from another OS that works fine and be the same version, rename the old dll something like 'System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll.old' and then copy the dll from the OS that works fine and restart IIS, usually the path is something like 'The_drive_letter:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Web.28b9ef5a#\db83bf9b99ce2a0365303cb922537538' inside is the 'System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll' and 'System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll.aux', change both.